# Приложение не видит константы при подключении их через composer.autoload.files

Tags: php, composer, php-fpm

Имеется `index.php` в котором подключен

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
require('./config/config.php');
```

есть `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/"
        ],
        "files": [
            "config/config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

В `config.php` описаны константы:

```
const API_TYPE_TELEGRAM = 'telegram';
const API_TYPE_WHATSAPP = 'whatsapp';
const API_TYPE_DISCORD = 'discord';
```

Неймспейс там не задан. Это просто некий конфигурационный файл + константы приложения.
Они будут использоваться в других файлах.

Теперь когда запускаю `index.php`, то в логи в ошибки мне пишет:

> Notice: constant API_TYPE_TELEGRAM already defined in php
> Notice: constant API_TYPE_WHATSAPP already defined in php
> Notice: constant API_TYPE_DISCORD already defined in php

Хотя нигде я больше их не объявляю. Окей. Думаю, может композер подключает через автолоад (т.к. его подключил и даже в `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php` есть сгенерированный массив подключения). Убираю строку `require('./config/config.php');` и получаю ошибку

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant API_TYPE_TELEGRAM

Что происходит? Где именно проблема? Если в `composer.autoload.files` прописан путь, то в других файлах уже не нужно его подключать? Или нужно? Если не нужно, то как тогда заставить приложение и классы видеть те константы?  А если нужно подключать файл, то зачем тогда строка в composer?

---

Само приложение работает, 9 раз из 10. Не знаю проблема в этом или нет. Но хотелось бы понять пока как делать правильно с комопзером и файлами

**UPD** Весь конфиг выглядит так:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

const API_TYPE_TELEGRAM = 'telegram';
const API_TYPE_WHATSAPP = 'whatsapp';
const API_TYPE_DISCORD = 'discord';

$config = [
    API_TYPE_TELEGRAM => [
        'token' => '',
        'chat_id' => '',
        'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    ],
    API_TYPE_WHATSAPP => [],
    API_TYPE_DISCORD => [],
];
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` делали? `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` делали?

Comment: @ArchDemon да, первое делал, второе в вопросе уже неписано) А нет, второе не делал. только require делал. Попробую

Comment: @ArchDemon второе тоже не помагает. Более того. Странность происходит в том, что если писать `require './config/config.php';` то пишет ошибку что константа уже определена, а если написать  `require_once './config/config.php';`, то ниже пишет, что переменная `$config` не определена (она тоже лежит в файле `config.php`). То есть получается, что композер как бы подключает файл но не совсем? :D  Какая-то непонятная магия и дичь происходит

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил в конец вопроса то, как выглядит конфиг файл. Он совсем незамысловатый

Comment: Попробуйте определять константу через [функцию define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155536/what-is-the-best-practice-for-adding-constants-in-laravel-long-list), нежели чем через const.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov увы, но тоже самое.  API_TYPE_TELEGRAM already defined и т.д. Я конечно могу написать `if (!defined` . НО это как-то глупо будет. Либо убрать из композера строчки с files. Но тогда зачем такая возможность была сделана? Очень странно всё

Comment: @AntonS., покажите как вы используете переменную `$config`? Ведь при подключенном `config.php ` через только автозагрузку,  она будет недоступна в проекте.

Comment: @AntonS., замените 2ю строку в `index.php` на `echo API_TYPE_TELEGRAM; exit`. Выводит значение константы?

Comment: @Jigius "при подключении через только автозагрузку, она будет недоступна в проекте." понятно. а я думал там автоматически идёт require файла. Ведь В autoload_real так и написано. А в целом конфиг применяю сразу ниже по коду в том же файле, пишу `new ConfigReader::get($config);`

Comment: вместо инициализации в файле `config.php` массивом параметров переменной `$config` - определите ф-ю `config` которая возвращает этот массив и используйте ее так: `ConfigReader::get(config());`

Comment: @Jigius да я вообще решил в виде класса сделать и подключать автолоадом так же, как и `app/` а секцию `"files": [ "config/config.php" ]` выпилить. Просто мне странно, что в композер заложена функция с определением файлов и он их подключает через require, но при этом так работает

Comment: У вас ошибка в архитектуре/концепции кода. Для автозагрузки через composer (да и не только для него), нужно писать код без побочных эффектов. Т.е. подключение файла не должно влиять на существующий код.  В вашем же случае подключение файла приведёт к переопределению переменной $config, если она уже существовала. Если бы вы поместили код файла в функцию, как вам тут советовали, то побочный эффект пропал бы.

Comment: https://ru.code-basics.com/languages/php/lessons/side-effects ссылка для размышления. В PSR-1 так же указывается на недопустимость побочных эффектов. Так же если вы сделаете `echo 'объявляю константы';` то станет видно, что они загружаются несколько раз